# Windows phone: After resuming timer, timer counts twice as fast

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am using DispatcherTimer class in order to use Timer in my app. I use a timer in a for loop as follow:

```
enter code here

   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
           dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1,0);
           dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
           dispatcherTimer.Start();
           temp = 0;
        }
    }

    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      txt.Text = temp.Tostring();
      if(temp<10)
        temp++;
      else
        dispatcherTimer.Stop();
    }
```

first iteration it works correctly and add the temp each second but second iteration will sum the temp with 2 rather than temp++ and, the third iteration it will sum the temp with three.

Do you have any idea that how can I solve this problem that each time sum temp by one rather than two or three?

Thanks,
~B

Comment: Thanks Mitch, Do you have any idea that how can I solve this problem that each time sum temp by one rather than two or three?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unbind your tick handler when you stop the timer:

```
dispatcherTimer.Stop();
dispatcherTimer.Tick -= dispatcherTimer_Tick;
```